# Python: Converting a seconds to a datetime format in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, seconds

Currently I am working with a big dataframe (12x47800). One of the twelve columns is a column consisting of an integer number of seconds. I want to change this column to a column consisting of a datetime.time format. Schedule is my dataframe where I try changing the column named 'depTime'. Since I want it to be a datetime.time and it could cross midnight i added the if-statement. This 'works' but really slow as one could imagine. Is there a faster way to do this?
My current code, the only one I could get working is:

```
for i in range(len(schedule)):
    t_sec = schedule.iloc[i].depTime
    [t_min, t_sec] = divmod(t_sec,60)
    [t_hour,t_min] = divmod(t_min,60)
    if t_hour>23:
        t_hour -= 23
    schedule['depTime'].iloc[i] = dt.time(int(t_hour),int(t_min),int(t_sec))
```

Thanks in advance guys.

Ps: I'm pretty new to Python, so if anybody could help me I would be very gratefull :)

Comment: Can you provide a short example of your data? For exampe `schedule.head(20)`

Comment: Are you certain that your column records the *time of day* and not *duration*? There is a difference, the time of day is constrained to [0-86400) seconds (86401 for leap seconds), duration is not constrained and can be negative. *Monty crossed the finish line at 10 past 3 in the afternoon, in a time of 2 hours 35 minutes and 5 seconds* has a time of day and a duration. You want to use `timedelta` for durations, not `time`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm adding a new solution which is much faster than the original since it relies on pandas vectorized functions instead of looping (pandas apply functions are essentially optimized loops on the data).

I tested it with a sample similar in size to yours and the difference is from 778ms to 21.3ms. So I definitely recommend the new version.

Both solutions are based on transforming your seconds integers into timedelta format and adding it to a reference datetime. Then, I simply capture the time component of the resulting datetimes.

New (Faster) Option:

```
import datetime as dt

seconds = pd.Series(np.random.rand(50)*100).astype(int) # Generating test data

start = dt.datetime(2019,1,1,0,0) # You need a reference point

datetime_series = seconds.astype('timedelta64[s]') + start

time_series = datetime_series.dt.time

time_series
```

Original (slower) Answer:

Not the most elegant solution, but it does the trick.

```
import datetime as dt

seconds = pd.Series(np.random.rand(50)*100).astype(int) # Generating test data

start = dt.datetime(2019,1,1,0,0) # You need a reference point

time_series = seconds.apply(lambda x: start + pd.Timedelta(seconds=x)).dt.time
```

Comment: This solution seems to work really good. Since my code needs to be run in realtime (eventually) time is of the essence and it works quite fast. Could you maybe elaborate a little more on how and why it works?

Comment: @Hestaron I've proposed a new solution which seems to work better. Would recommend you take a look.

Comment: `astype('timedelta64[ms]'`) converts the numbers to **milliseconds**, no seconds, then adds an arbitrary epoch and extracts the time object from that with `.dt.time`. Apart from using milliseconds instead of seconds, it is only slightly faster than using `pd.to_datetime(seconds, unit='s').dt.time` (586 us vs 714 us).

Answer (score 5):

You should try not to do a full scan on a dataframe, but instead use vectorized access because it is normally much more efficient.

Fortunately, pandas has a function that does exactly what you are asking for, `to_timedelta`:

```
schedule['depTime'] = pd.to_timedelta(schedule['depTime'], unit='s')
```

It is not really a datetime format, but it is the pandas equivalent of a `datetime.timedelta` and is a convenient type for processing times. You could use `to_datetime` but will end with a full datetime close to 1970-01-01...

If you really need `datetime.time` objects, you can get them that way:

```
schedule['depTime'] = pd.to_datetime(schedule['depTime'], unit='s').dt.time
```

but they are less convenient to use in a pandas dataframe.

Comment: This seemed like a fitting solution and I tried it with the to_datetime. This seems pretty close to what I want to achieve but the problem is that I get a datetime.datetime which I then still need to convert to a datetime.time format. I tried to use the .time but I got the  'Series' object has no attribute 'time'. Which I understand. Is there from this point an easy way to convert the datetime.datetime to datetime.time?

Comment: @Hestaron: `time` attribute can help here: see my edit.

Comment: Conversion to timedeltas this way certainly beats conversion to time objects, if someone was looking for performance reasons.